# Get value for CSS declaration inside HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I am a newbie to CSS selectors and I am trying to get the value for a CSS declaration item assigned to the value attribute:

```
<input id="textUsername_ClientState" name="textUsername_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":"","validationText":"Tom","valueAsString":"Tom","lastSetTextBoxValue":"Tom"}">
```

Basically I am trying to pull back one of the "Tom" values. I tried **document.getElementById("textUsername_ClientState").value.style.getPropertyValue("valueAsString")** but it didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear.value is an attribute of an input field. Here you are trying to pass an object(apparently) to value field

Comment: Your `input` is invalid due to bad quotes, try this: `<input id="textUsername_ClientState" name="textUsername_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value='{"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":"","validationText":"Tom","valueAsString":"Tom","lastSetTextBoxValue":"Tom"}'>` ... and value has no style, so getPropertyValue is probably not going to work

Comment: It kind of looks like you're trying to set your input field to hold a JSON string, but JSON isn't CSS, values don't have styles and you're using a whole bunch of CSS attributes that don't exist.

Comment: This wasn't my code. I was trying to pullout these values and pass then to an (analytics)  tag manager.  The JSON.parse method did it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a newbie you have to learn a lot. You should be correct in declaring tag and its attribute

### value=" { "enabled":true, "emptyMessage":"", "validationText":"Tom", "valueAsString":"Tom", "lastSetTextBoxValue":"Tom"} "

This line has some syntax error

correct form is

### value='{ "enabled":"true", "emptyMessage":"", "validationText":"Tom", "valueAsString":"Tom", "lastSetTextBoxValue":"Tom"}'

Learn the difference between ' and ".
This is the format of JSON string. In this question you have to tried to access the value of valueAsString

before trying to get the value,you need to convert the json string to a javascript array by using JSON.parse() method. After parsing you can access the values individually.

I hope this helps.

Html:

```
<body>

<input id="textUsername_ClientState" name="textUsername_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value='{"enabled":"true","emptyMessage":"","validationText":"Tom","valueAsString":"Tom","lastSetTextBoxValue":"Tom"}'>
<button onclick="cool()">Cool</button>

<script>

function cool()
{
a=document.getElementById("textUsername_ClientState").value;
b=JSON.parse(a);
alert(b.valueAsString); 
}

</script>


</body>
```